# What is the right adhesive to use with PVC interior paneling and trim?

Tags: adhesive, pvc

We purchased interior PVC paneling and baseboard for a project. We are unsure as to which adhesive is best to bond it to both a mortar and sheetrock surface.  We received conflicting answers to our question at the store we purchased it from. Does anyone have personal experience with this product that can answer this question definitively?

Answer (score 1):

There is a product

Roberts cove moulding adhesive - I am sure there are other things better and worse.

Something I consider critical for the project is a Cove shozzle, again a roberts product - it fits on a caulking tube of the stuff, well i guess anyone's product in a caulk tube, and spreads it out wide, so you do not get the kind of squish out, or one thick line of the stuff on the moulding.

Comment: I researched the product and the applicator ~ this looks like what we need. The adhesive can be used for vinyl baseboard, so I assume it can be used with our PVC product also.

Comment: Things of this type all start to become grouped together under the term 'Construction Adhesive'. Much of it starts to seem alike. With the creative name of Roberts and id numbers - it sounds like a house brand for someone that make it for everyone, not the best but far from the worst. Large temperature changes and differential of expansion between materials coul call for unique products. I do not see the need for a high-end formulation by 3M needed. More painting attention to spreading the glue, than the exact product. Seems to matter here. Just my thoughts.